# I want to set a variable to store the file name only

Tags: batch-file

Below code was works fine. This will output shown "TF-IPHB160240_JATS".

```
@echo off
set file="D:\Backup\12-14-2016\tool\TF-IPHB160240_JATS.xml"
FOR %%i in ("%file%") do echo %%~ni
```

I want to set a variable to store the file name. below is what I have tried but it is not working.

```
@echo off
set file="D:\Backup\12-14-2016\tool\TF-IPHB160240_JATS.xml"
FOR %%i in ("%file%") do (
set view=%%~ni
echo %view%
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have a parenthesis missing in your code, I think you are trying to echo the variable inside a for loop. For that you'll need to use delayed expansion.

However it's not necessary to echo it inside the loop

```bat
@Echo off
Set "file=D:\Backup\12-14-2016\tool\TF-IPHB160240_JATS.xml"
For %%i In ("%file%") Do Set "view=%%~ni"
Echo=%view%
Pause
```

Here it is using delayed expansion

```bat
@Echo off
Set "file=D:\Backup\12-14-2016\tool\TF-IPHB160240_JATS.xml"
For %%i In ("%file%") Do (Set "view=%%~ni"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo=!view!
    EndLocal)
Pause
```